# Save buffer immediately after org-archive-location

Tags: org-mode

## Question

How do I immediately save the `.org` buffer created by `org-archive-location`?

## Context and what I've tried so far

Current `.emacs` settings:

```
FILE: .emacs
(setq org-archive-location (concat "~/Documents/Reference/org/archive/" (format-time-string "%Y-%m") ".org::"))
```

Consider

```
FILE: main2.org
* Done item
```

Calling `org-archive-location` with `C-c $` results in the following buffers

```
FILE: *Messages*
Subtree archived in file: ~/Documents/Reference/org/archive/2019-06.org
```

and

```
FILE: 2019-06.org
Archived entries from file /Users/janmeppe/Documents/Reference/org/main2.org


* Done item 
:PROPERTIES:
:ARCHIVE_TIME: 2019-06-18 Tue 11:26
:ARCHIVE_FILE: ~/Documents/Reference/org/main2.org
:ARCHIVE_CATEGORY: main2
:END:
```

Now the problem is this, I have to manually save the buffer for it to appear in the finder, how do I automatically save this buffer after calling `org-archive-location`?

I tried adding the following but it this help

```
(advice-add 'org-archive-location :after #'org-save-all-org-buffers)
```

Answer (score 5):

`org-archive-location` is *not* a function that can be modified with `advice`.  It is a variable.  Perhaps the O.P. meant to say `org-archive-subtree`?  Type `C-h k` (aka `M-x describe-key`) and then the keyboard shortcut to see what function is triggered ....

```lisp
(advice-add 'org-archive-subtree :after #'org-save-all-org-buffers)
```

---

I would prefer to save only the buffer containing the archived subtree *and* the buffer from which it was archived/removed, but that would take some additional digging into the code and doing some testing ... Perhaps another forum participant would like to write up an alternate answer that uses a scalpel instead of the `org-save-all-org-buffers` (which is a sledgehammer).

Comment: No time to dig either, but `org-archive-hook` runs after successfully archiving a subtree, with point in the original file.  There is also the variable `org-archive-location` which indicates where subtrees should be archived for the current file.  Unfortunately, `org-archive-location` uses some bizarro syntax which isn't a file path.  If someone can figure out how to expand the `org-archive-location` into a normal file system path,  then `org-archive-hook` could be made to 1. save the current org file and 2. the corresponding archive file.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround with the same functionality but it works on calling `save-buffer` which I call often with `:w` in evil. I'm not marking this as the correct answer because it does not answer the question (i.e. how to save immediately after `org-archive-location`) but I'd like to share it because it results in the same functionality.

```
(advice-add 'save-buffer :after #'org-save-all-org-buffers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since at least Org 9.4 there's a variable which controls when to save the archive file: `org-archive-subtree-save-file-p`. From the docs:

```
Conditionally save the archive file after archiving a subtree.

This variable can be any of the following symbols:

t              saves in all cases.
from-org     prevents saving from an agenda-view.
from-agenda  saves only when the archive is initiated from an agenda-view.
nil            prevents saving in all cases.

Note that, regardless of this value, the archive buffer is never
saved when archiving into a location in the current buffer.
```